# Multiple inheritance using `BaseBranchOperator` in Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

Can one use multiple inheritance using `BaseBranchOperator` in Airflow?

I want to define an operator like:

```
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.operators.branch import BaseBranchOperator


class MyOperator(BaseOperator, BaseBranchOperator):

    def execute(self, context):
        print('hi')

    def choose_branch(self, context):
        if True:
            return 'task_A'
        else:
            return 'task_B'
```

In that case, is it accurate to think that the `execute` method will run before the `choose_branch` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Elad Kalif for your answer. That was inspiring.

However, I've [learned](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/concepts.html) that `pre_execute` has not access to the `context` variable.

> Current context is accessible only during the task execution. The context is not accessible during pre_execute or post_execute. Calling this method outside execution context will raise an error.

Another solution I've found was to make it like this:

```
from airflow.operators.branch import BaseBranchOperator
from myoperator import MyOperator


class MyBranchOperator(MyOperator, BaseBranchOperator):

    def __init__(
        self,
        next_tasks={"success": None, "failure": None},
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    )
    MyOperator.__init__(
            self,
            *args,
            **kwargs,
        )
        self.next_tasks = next_tasks

    def execute(self, context):
        if something_wrong:
            err_msg = f'Ops'
            raise ValueError(err_msg)

        print('hi')

        branches_to_execute = self.choose_branch(context)
        self.skip_all_except(context["ti"], branches_to_execute)
        return branches_to_execute

    def choose_branch(self, context):
        if True:  // plug condition here
            return self.next_tasks["success"]
        else:
            return self.next_tasks["failure"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This won't work.

In Airflow each operator has execute function that set the operator logic. In case of `BaseBranchOperator` the `execute` function leverages [`choose_branch`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2242ea4ec1e48278d7b65bf2dfda8151c912546d/airflow/operators/branch.py#L41-L51) and handle the logic of how to skip tasks, so all user left to do is just say what task to skip and this is done in `choose_branch`:

```
def choose_branch(self, context: Context) -> str | Iterable[str]:
    """
    Abstract method to choose which branch to run.

    Subclasses should implement this, running whatever logic is
    necessary to choose a branch and returning a task_id or list of
    task_ids.

    :param context: Context dictionary as passed to execute()
    """
    raise NotImplementedError
```

So when you want to implement your own branch operator all you need to do is inherit from `BaseBranchOperator` and override the `choose_branch` function.

You can decide that you don't want this mechanism and you want to build your own branch logic which means that you will need to implement the logic of how to skip tasks. In that case you will implement `MyBaseBranchOperator` and then your actual branch operator (In your case `MyOperator`) will be:

```
class MyOperator(MyBaseBranchOperator):
    ...
```

I think what you are really after is [`pre_execute()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/25e0e30099e13a3cb7d3d7ffd16989dc48ade3e8/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L1109-L1112) which triggers  right before `execute()` is called

So probably what you want is:

```
class MyOperator(BaseBranchOperator):

    def pre_execute(self, context):
        print('hi')

    def choose_branch(self, context):
        if True:
            return 'task_A'
        else:
            return 'task_B'
```

Comment: Can one make something like:

```
class MyOperator(BaseBranchOperator):

    def execute(self, context):
        print('hi')

    def pre_execute(self, context):
        self.choose_branch(context)

    def choose_branch(self, context):
        if True:
            return 'task_A'
        else:
            return 'task_B'
```
to enable the `choose_branch` method to run before everything else?

Comment: Omg formatting on these comments is awful. Please let me know if that's clear enough

Comment: `choose_branch` is running as part of the `execute()`.

Comment: I'm still finding ways to test it out.. Wil do that asap

Comment: Please vote question up if you think that's relevant for the community